# Password Program In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I am new to Python and I wrote this password program in Python but the first 'elif' statement doesn't execute for some reason. If i input a password that has less than 5 characters AND has a special character in it, it just says that it's too short whereas it's supposed to say it's too short AND you can't use special characters. Any help would be appreciated.

```
password = 'Chubz'
count = 3
listA = list("'#$%&\()@*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'")

while count >= 0:
    x = input('What is the pass? ')
    if x in listA:
        print(f" {count} You can't use special characters ")
        count -= 1
    elif x in listA and len(x) < 5:
        print(f"{count} You can't use special characters and the pass is too short")
        count -= 1
    elif len(x) < 5:
        print(f'{count} Pass is too short')
        count -= 1
    elif x != password:
        print(f'{count} Try again')
        count -= 1
    else:
        print('Access Granted')
        break
```

Comment: `x` is a string. You want to check if any of characters within `x` is a special character. To do that, you have to iterate through `x`. You cannot just do `if x in listA`

Comment: Well how do I write the code for that?

Comment: see my response below. It gives you the details. I have also explained any() function.

Comment: To learn more about [any()](https://beginnersbook.com/2019/03/python-any-function/) use this link. Similar to  any(), you also have [all()](https://beginnersbook.com/2019/03/python-all-function/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking it in the order you have, why don't you check it in the below order. It will ensure the elif gets executed only if the previous condition is not satisfied.

Also, you need to check for each character of x instead of the whole string of x.

To do that you can use [any()](https://beginnersbook.com/2019/03/python-any-function/#:%7E:text=Python%20any()%20function%20accepts,any()%20method%20returns%20false.)

```
any([True for i in x if i in listA])
```

This will be set to True if any of the characters in `x` is a special character.

```
password = 'Chubz'
count = 3
listA = list("'#$%&\()@*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'")

while count >= 0:
    x = input('What is the pass? ')
    if len(x) < 5:
        print(f'{count} Pass is too short')
        count -= 1
    elif any([True for i in x if i in listA]):
        print(f" {count} You can't use special characters ")
        count -= 1
    elif x != password:
        print(f'{count} Try again')
        count -= 1
    else:
        print('Access Granted')
        break
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this one worked. I just had to add the any([True for i in x if i in listA])
for 2 of the if statements.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. If you think this answered your question, please read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question. Upvote the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: using the any() twice is costly. If you switch the if statements a bit, you need to do the any only once like I did in my example. Both works.

Answer (score 3):

```
if x in listA:
    print(f" {count} You can't use special characters ")
    count -= 1

elif x in listA and len(x) < 5:
```

There is no way to reach this latter clause: it is a subset of the first one.  Anything that qualifies for the `elif` has already been handled by the `if`.  You need to switch the order of checks.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to swap the first 'if' statement with the first 'elif' statement?

Comment: At least that much, yes.  For the rest, you have to decide which error message  you want printed in case the user makes several mistakes in one input.

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is true and after that it will exit... it will never reach to first elif. you need to add the seconds condition as well in elif.

```
if x in listA and len(x) > 5::
    print(f" {count} You can't use special characters ")
    count -= 1
```

Basically if statements work best if they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, just put
`elif x in listA and len(x) < 5: print(f"{count} You can't use special characters and the pass is too short") count -= 1`
Before the first if statement so this would become the if statement instead of elif.
The interpreter reads from up to down so it saw that a special character was used to directly printed it.

SO the code would be:
`if x in listA and len(x) > 5:`
`print(f" {count} You can't use special characters ")`

`count -= 1`

Comment: I already tried putting swapping their places but it still didn't work...

Comment: It should; are you on the latest version of Python: 3.8.5?

Comment: I'm on 3.8.0 but I don't think it matters

Comment: `x` is a string. so PO needs to check for each character of `x` against the list.